# Turn off field programmatically in ArcMap via VB.Net

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, vb.net

I'm creating an addin button in Arcmap via VB.net that when clicked, runs the identify tool. But I want only selected fields to appear in the identify dialog. My idea is to hide the unnecessary fields and then show them again once the identify tool is deactivated.

Is it possible to programmatically turn off/on a field?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the IFieldInfo::Visible property. Here's one way

```
Dim pFieldInfo As IFieldInfo 
Dim pLayerFields As ILayerFields

pLayerFields = pMxDoc.FocusMap.Layer(0)
pFieldInfo = pLayerFields.FieldInfo(lIndex)
pFieldInfo.Visible = False
```